# How to Configure Jenkins to insert the same data related to build of the jobs in jenkins to two different databases?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to configure Jenkins to store the data related to the status , start, end time of the jobs build into the MSSQL server database. I need to configure jenkins to insert the same data to another Database inaddition to the above database. How to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataBasePlugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Database+Plugin and configure it

Or

You can write a shell script command to connect and insert the data into the DB

```
   #!bin/bash
query="insert into table_name values(....)"
mysql -u username -p password mysql -e "$query";
```

Comment: how can i run this for pgsql database ?